# Django: Pass form value element id or classname

Tags: python, django, templates, element, formset

I have the following form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["name", "surname", "idnumber"]

MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(MyModel,
                                 form=MyForm,
                                 extra=0)
```

In views.py:

```
def completeForm(request):
    formset = MyFormSet(queryset=MyModel.objects.all())
    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

So, in my template I would like to do the following:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
  <p id="{{ form.name }}">{{ form.name }}</p>
  <p id="{{ form.surname }}">{{ form.surname }}</p>
  <p id="{{ form.idnumber }}">{{ form.idnumber }}</p>
{% endfor %}}
```

This does not really work..  Is there a way to do this or should I add ids in the form widgets?  If so, how can I do this in the forms.py?

Comment: What? `{{ form.name }}` outputs an `input` element that includes an ID already. You can't use the same ID for two separate HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

The form  needs to simply be :

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
  {{ form.name }}
  {{ form.surname }}
  {{ form.idnumber }}
{% endfor %}}
```

This should work. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I should looking for [attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances) of widgets. In a simple form you could just do like this:

```
class FormLogin(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=40, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

In a [modelform](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
    class MyForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["name", "surname", "idnumber"]
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'name', 'class':'form-control'}),
            'surname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'idnumber': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```